# BruteForceMatcher_GPU matcher Error

Tags: opencv, cuda, gpu

I'm using Opencv 2.4.6.0 with Cuda 5.5 on Ubuntu 12.04
After executing the code I get the following error when the execution reaches the

```
atcher.knnMatch(descriptors_test_GPU, descriptors_tmp_GPU, matches, 2);

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (func != 0) in knnMatchSingle, file /root/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/gpu/src/brute_force_matcher.cpp, line 497
```

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /root/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/gpu/src/brute_force_matcher.cpp:497: error: (-215) func != 0 in function knnMatchSingle

Code sample here:

```
Mat image = imread(argv[1]);
resize(image, image, Size(600,450), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
Mat image_gray;
getGray(image, image_gray);

ORB_GPU orb(1000);

GpuMat descriptors_test_GPU, frame_g(image_gray);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_test_CPU;

GpuMat fullmask(frame_g.size(), CV_8U, 0xFF);

orb(frame_g, GpuMat(), keypoints_test_CPU, descriptors_test_GPU);

Mat descriptors_test_CPU_Mat(descriptors_test_GPU);

vector<Point2f> objs_corners(4);
BruteForceMatcher_GPU< L2<float> > matcher;

VideoCapture cap;
Mat currentFrame_c;
vector< vector<DMatch> > matches;
matches.clear();

if ( cap.open(argv[2]) ) {
    do
    {
        cap >> currentFrame_c;
        resize(currentFrame_c, currentFrame_c, Size(600,450), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
        getGray(currentFrame_c, currentFrame_c);

        GpuMat currentFrame(currentFrame_c);
        //Get the corners from the object
        objs_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
        objs_corners[1] = cvPoint( currentFrame.cols, 0 );
        objs_corners[2] = cvPoint( currentFrame.cols, currentFrame.rows );
        objs_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, currentFrame.rows );

        //cout<<endl<<objs_corners[0]<<" "<<objs_corners[1]<<" "<<objs_corners[2]<<" "<<objs_corners[3]<<endl;
        GpuMat keypoints_tmp_GPU, descriptors_tmp_GPU;
        vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_tmp_CPU;
        orb(currentFrame, GpuMat(), keypoints_test_CPU, descriptors_tmp_GPU);
        GpuMat trainIdx, distance;

        matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_test_GPU, descriptors_tmp_GPU, matches, 2);

        std::vector<DMatch > good_matches;

        for(int k = 0; k < min(descriptors_test_CPU_Mat.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); k++) //THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
        {
            if((matches[k][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[k][1].distance)) && ((int) matches[k].size()<=2 && (int) matches[k].size()>0))
            {
                good_matches.push_back(matches[k][0]);
            }
        }                    

        matcher.clear();

    } while (!currentFrame_c.empty());
}
```

I can't understand, I'm not even using `knnMatchSingle`.
If I remove the line the code works.

Comment: The same Assertion func != 0 throws for any match function I use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ORB` descriptor extractor returns 8-bit descriptors. Use `Hamming` distance for this descriptors:

```
BruteForceMatcher_GPU<Hamming> matcher;
matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_test_GPU, descriptors_tmp_GPU, matches, 2);
```

BruteForceMatcher_GPU with L2 norm supports only float descriptors (like from `SURF`).

Comment: Thanks a million, that solved my error!. But now my number of matches are the same with the keypoints size.

Comment: It is expected behavior. BruteForceMatcher finds for each keypoint in first set nearest keypoints from second set, so output size of matches array is the same as the number of keypoints in first set.

Comment: I tried to modify the code to match my CPU version. My CPU version returns good matches, how can I make my GPU version to return good matches ass well?